# Javascript prototype shared values confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following code:

```
function Bar() {
}

Bar.prototype.c = 0;

var foo = new Bar();
foo.c = 20;

var test = new Bar();
console.log(test.c);
```

The value I get in the console is 0. I thought that these objects would **share the same prototype object**, thus the output would be 20. Why is this not so?

Comment: Its called shadowing, providing a value on the instance or closer to the instance in the prototype chain. That and more is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 mutate a prototype value on an instance and it'll change the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do share the same prototype.

However, when you set `foo.c`, you're setting a property on `foo`, not its prototype.